# How to override Content Security Policy (CSP)?

Tags: google-chrome, content-security-policy

During the development of an application it turned out that some script which creates iframe and calls external resource throws following exception:

> Refused to frame 'https://someaddres.com/' because an ancestor
> violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
> "frame-ancestors 'self' *.somedomain.com *.other.domain etc.

The iframe works on test environment, but not locally, on dev machine.

Is there any simple way to override CSP for development purposes?

Answer (score 1):

You can override HTTP response headers in Chrome. [Here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/overrides/#override-headers) is step by step guide.

On the Network tab of dev tools you must find which request causes trouble. Then you must override existing policy. Easiest way would be wildcard rule (on the Sources tab, .headers file):

[image]

Detailed description of how to override response headers you can find in the linked guide on Chrome website.